# Python 3: How to fix FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, export-to-csv

Disclaimer: I am fairly new to python so sorry in advance for lack of coding knowledge. 
I am pulling historical data from Yahoo Finance and want to run a trading strategy through it. I got the backtest to work for the most part, but for efficiency and readability I decided to try to create a class with more explicitly defined variables. When I fetch the data, I want to download it as a csv file so I don't have to re-fetch the data every time I run it. That being said, when I try to use my variables in the creation of the file name of the csv, I get the FileNotFoundError. But if I just hard code in the name, it works creates the csv no problem. I have tried multiple different ways of using my variables for the file name but none work except hard coding. Can someone help me understand what is going on?

```
##Working Code:
class backtest:

    def __init__(self, ticker):

        start = '1/3/2000'
        end = '1/3/2019'
        sdate = pd.to_datetime(start)
        edate = pd.to_datetime(end)


        if os.path.islink('{}_{}_to_{}.csv'.format(ticker, start, end)) == True:
            self.df = pd.read_csv('{}_{}_to_{}.csv'.format(ticker, start, end), parse_dates=True)

        else:
            ##Failed attempt 1
            ##self.filename = '{}_{}_to_{}.csv'.format(ticker, start, end)
            ##self.df.to_csv(self.filename)

            ##Failed attempt 2
            ##self.filename = str(ticker) + '_' + start + '_to_' + end + '.csv'            
            ##self.df.to_csv(self.filename)

            self.df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', sdate, edate)
            self.df.to_csv('amzn_1/3/2000_to_1/3/19.csv')



amzn = backtest('amzn')
print(amzn.df.head(1))
```

Comment: Are `end = '1/3/2019'` and `self.df.to_csv('amzn_1/3/2000_to_1/3/19')` related, by any chance? I'm wondering if this is a typo...

Comment: You can't have "/" in a file name, You can just see by trying to rename any filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For making the file name try:

`self.filename = str(ticker) + '_' + str(sdate) +  '_to_' + str(edate) + '.csv'`

here, sdate and edate are `class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'`. So they have to be converted to string while appending.

The result in the console would be:

`High  ...  Adj Close
Date                 ...
2000-01-03  89.5625  ...     89.375`

And the file name would be `amzn_2000-01-03 00:00:00_to_2019-01-0300:00:00.csv`. As  mentioned in the comments above, filename not supposed to contain special char '/'. So using sdate instead of strat.

Comment: This helped a lot thanks! So why can I use the '/' in a file name if I hard code the file name?

Comment: These type of special characters have separate functionality and may affect the operating system if used improperly. 
Slash is generally used as a separator for separating the directories or files in the directories. 
Even somehow due to limitations( I am not sure), slash is used in a file name, there are higher chances that the OS might get confused and might interpret it in a wrong way.

Comment: For me even if I hard code '/' in file name using your code I am getting error:

` File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 3020, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/csvs.py", line 157, in save
    compression=self.compression)
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 424, in _get_handle
    f = open(path_or_buf, mode, encoding=encoding, newline="")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'amzn_1/3/2000_to_1/3/19.csv'`